Component not found
I have below implementation to integrate with blob storage
daprblob.yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: blobstore
spec:
  type: state.azure.blobstorage
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: accountName
    value: "***"
  - name: containerName
    value: "***"
  - name: "accountKey"
    value: "***"

And im invoking by this block in c#
private const string _blobStoreName = "blobstore";
[HttpPost("saveDataToBlob")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> SaveDataToBlob([FromBody] InputMessage message, [FromServices] DaprClient daprClient)
{


    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "blobName", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() } };

    await daprClient.InvokeBindingAsync<InputMessage>(_blobStoreName, "create", message, metadata: data);
    return new OkObjectResult(message);
}

Below is log running dapr cli
    Starting Dapr with id shielddeep-lion. HTTP Port: 59363. gRPC Port: 59364
info    Starting Dapr Runtime -- version 1.13.1 -- commit 1b3c48066dfcb68e0bb15e6096fcfac862375b75
info    Log level set to: debug
warning mTLS is disabled. Skipping certificate request and tls validation
warning The default value for 'spec.metric.http.increasedCardinality' will change to 'false' in Dapr 1.14
debug   Found 0 resiliency configurations in resources path
debug   Hot reloading disabled
info    standalone mode configured
info    app id: shielddeep-lion
info    metrics server started on :59365/
info    Dapr trace sampler initialized: DaprTraceSampler(P=1.000000)
info    local service entry announced: shielddeep-lion -> 192.168.2.20:59366
info    Initialized name resolution to mdns
debug   the current OS does not support pluggable components feature, skipping initialization
info    Loading componentsΓÇª
debug   Found component: blobstore (state.azure.blobstorage/v1)
info    Waiting for all outstanding components to be processedΓÇª
debug   Loading component: blobstore (state.azure.blobstorage/v1)
warning WARNING: state store state.azure.blobstorage/v1 is deprecated and will be removed in a future version, please use state.azure.blobstorage/v2
info    Component loaded: blobstore (state.azure.blobstorage/v1)
info    All outstanding components processed
info    Loading endpointsΓÇª
info    Waiting for all outstanding components to be processedΓÇª
debug   Loading component: blobstore (state.azure.blobstorage/v1)
warning WARNING: state store state.azure.blobstorage/v1 is deprecated and will be removed in a future version, please use state.azure.blobstorage/v2
info    Component loaded: blobstore (state.azure.blobstorage/v1)
info    All outstanding components processed
info    Loading endpointsΓÇª
info    Waiting for all outstanding http endpoints to be processedΓÇª
info    All outstanding http endpoints processed
debug   Refreshing channels
debug   Channels refreshed
info    gRPC server listening on TCP address: :59364
info    Enabled gRPC tracing middleware
info    Enabled gRPC metrics middleware
info    Registering workflow engine for gRPC endpoint: [::]:59364
info    API gRPC server is running on port 59364
info    Enabled max body size HTTP middleware with size 4 MB
info    Enabled tracing HTTP middleware
info    Enabled metrics HTTP middleware
info    HTTP server listening on TCP address: :59363
info    HTTP server is running on port 59363
info    The request body size parameter is: 4
info    gRPC server listening on TCP address: :59366
info    Enabled gRPC tracing middleware
info    Enabled gRPC metrics middleware
info    Internal gRPC server is running on port 59366
info    application protocol: http. waiting on port 58569.  This will block until the app is listening on that port.
== APP == D:\Work\Containerapp\ContainerApps\Flooid\FlooidCommon\FlooidCommon.csproj : warning NU1902: Package 'Azure.Identity' 1.10.4 has a known moderate severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wvxc-855f-jvrv [D:\Work\Containerapp\ContainerApps\Flooid\App\BasicStoreData.csproj]
== APP == D:\Work\Containerapp\ContainerApps\Flooid\FlooidCommon\FlooidCommon.csproj : warning NU1902: Package 'Azure.Identity' 1.10.4 has a known moderate severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wvxc-855f-jvrv
        Updating metadata for appPID: 42620
        Updating metadata for app command: dotnet run
        You're up and running! Both Dapr and your app logs will appear here....
2024/05/02 13:03:29 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": dial tcp [::1]:9411: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
== APP == info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
== APP ==       Now listening on: https://localhost:58569
== APP == info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
== APP ==       Now listening on: http://localhost:58564
== APP == info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
== APP ==       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
== APP == info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
== APP ==       Hosting environment: Development
== APP == info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
== APP ==       Content root path: D:\Work\Containerapp\ContainerApps\Flooid\App
info    application discovered on port 58569
info    actors: state store is not configured - this is okay for clients but services with hosted actors will fail to initialize!
info    Configuring actors placement provider 'placement'. Configuration: 'placement:localhost:6050'
info    Configuring actor reminders provider 'default'. Configuration: ''
info    Actor runtime started. Actor idle timeout: 1h0m0s. Actor scan interval: 30s
info    Configuring workflow engine with actors backend
info    Registering component for dapr workflow engine...
info    Initializing Dapr workflow component
info    Workflow engine initialized.
info    dapr initialized. Status: Running. Init Elapsed 8609ms
debug   try to connect to placement service: dns:///localhost:6050
debug   Error connecting to placement service (will retry to connect in background): rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = last connection error: ...
debug   rpc error: code = Internal desc = error invoking output binding blobstore: couldn't find output binding blobstore
debug   rpc error: code = Internal desc = error invoking output binding blobstore: couldn't find output binding blobstore
== APP == fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
== APP ==       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
== APP ==       Dapr.DaprException: Binding operation failed: the Dapr endpoint indicated a failure. See InnerException for details.
== APP ==        ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="error invoking output binding blobstore: couldn't find output binding blobstore")
== APP ==          at Dapr.Client.DaprClientGrpc.MakeInvokeBindingRequestAsync(String name, String operation, ByteString data, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
== APP ==          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
== APP ==          at Dapr.Client.DaprClientGrpc.MakeInvokeBindingRequestAsync(String name, String operation, ByteString data, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
== APP ==          at Dapr.Client.DaprClientGrpc.InvokeBindingAsync[TRequest](String bindingName, String operation, TRequest data, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
== APP ==          at BasicStoreData.Controllers.HomeController.SaveDataToBlob(InputMessage message, DaprClient daprClient) in D:\Work\Containerapp\ContainerApps\Flooid\App\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 242
== APP ==          at lambda_method7(Closure, Object)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Val
ueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
== APP ==          at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
== APP ==          at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
== APP ==          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2024/05/02 13:03:44 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": dial tcp [::1]:9411: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

log says blobstore component is loaded, but when trying to invoke gets exception its not found. Calling api like below also gives error
http://localhost:56736/v1.0/bindings/blobstore
response:
{
    "errorCode": "ERR_INVOKE_OUTPUT_BINDING",
    "message": "error invoking output binding blobstore: couldn't find output binding blobstore"
}

What could be issue here?

Blobstore can be state component or binding.
In your case, you defined it as state store,
  type: state.azure.blobstorage

but you are trying to access it as binding:
http://localhost:56736/v1.0/bindings/blobstore

If you want to use it as a binding, then declare it as such in your component file:
  type: bindings.azure.blobstorage

HTH
